# Excel lookup value within 3 columns and return value from 3rd columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm trying to lookup a value that is found in either of 3 columns. After finding the value in either of the 3 columns, I want to return the value from the 3rd column. How do I do this. See below.

`Code1     Code2      Code3
80281752 5000973    5000981
80281753 5000974    5000974
80281896 5000993    5000995
80281897 5000976    5000976
5000977  5000977    5000977`

For example, I want want to lookup 80281896 (found in 1st column) and have it return 5000995; Or lookup 5000973 (found in 2nd column) and have it return 5000981; Or lookup 5000980 (found in 3rd column) and have it return 3rd column. The lookup needs to search all 3 columns and return on the value in the 3rd column. I'm stumped!

Thank you.

Comment: my table didn't get formatted properly. There are 3 columns in the lookup range. If it finds a match in either of the 3 columns, I want to return the value in the 3rd column. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution.
In this example sample data is in Cells B3:D7. For this formula to work, you should leave one cell before the data which usually is your header row anyways.

In E3 put the lookup value.

In F3 put the following formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D3:D7,SUMPRODUCT((B3:D7=E3)*(ROW(B3:B7)-ROW($B$2)))/SUMPRODUCT(((B3:D7=E3)*1))),"Not Found")
```

This formula uses SUMPRODUCT to get the relative ROW number and wrapped in INDEX on third column retrieves the value from third column.

[image]

Comment: love the automation!

Answer (score 1):

Put the lookup value in **D1** and in **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX(C1:C6,IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C1:C6,0),MATCH(D1,B1:B6,0)),MATCH(D1,A1:A6,0)))
```

First try to match against column **C**; if that fails try column **B**;  if that fails, try column **A**.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a more general tool.*(for tables with lots of columns, nesting will be problematic)*

Say we have a two dimensional table of arbitrary size somewhere on the worksheet.  We want to lookup a value and return the value in the last column of that table.  Enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function LastKolumn(v As Variant, rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim nRow As Long, nKolumn As Long

    nKolumn = rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - 1
    nRow = rng.Find(what:=v, after:=rng(1)).Row

    LastKolumn = rng(nRow, nKolumn)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as *.xlsm* rather than *.xlsx*

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=LastKolumn(A1,B1:Z100)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**